# Annoying eclipse automatically closing quotes

Tags: eclipse

I've always found the eclipse's automatic close quotes and parenthesis features to be useless. For example hitting on a single " will lead to

```
"<cursor>"
```

I don't need the second quote.  It's annoying to remove afterward.  How to turn this feature off?

**Update:**  I now kept the setting on.  If you type another quote " it will break through.

Comment: I know this post is almost 4 years old, but in case others discover this just now as I have: You can hit tab to move your cursor to the highlighted location. This means you don't need to arrow key out of the qoutes/brackets/parens, etc. Pretty handy. I turned all closing back on once I discovered this.

Comment: Agreed. This is the kind of behaviour you can put up with in MS word but resent in Eclipse. When developers try to guess what users want, users end up trying to guess what developers guessed they needed in the first place.

Comment: Actually, I know have the setting turned on and just type another quote " to break through.

Comment: This is especially annoying when you want to break up a string by typing quotes inside an existing string. `"string" -> "stri" + ""ng"`... nonetheless, it's an additional press of the backspace/delete key. If only there was a setting for autocompletion in specific cases.

Comment: For Android Studio: Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Inser pair quote (uncheck).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing and uncheck the "Strings" checkbox in the "Automatically close" group.

Comment: @drevicko SEe a psychiatrist

Comment: For Perl, it's in Preferences > Perl EPIC > Editor > Smart Typing

Comment: I did all this but it's still auto-closing quotes in CSS files, arrrgh!

Comment: For Database Development, it's in Data Management > SQL Development > SQL Editor > Typing

Comment: In Preferences, search for "Strings". "Typing" > "Automatically close" > "Strings" (itself enclosed in quotation marks in the Preference dialog) showed up in multiple places. I cleared "Strings" in all of them. Seems to have helped...

Answer (score 21):

You need to turn this feature off for all editors:
Go to Preferences and in the "type filer text" box type "typing".
Then click on each result and un-check all unwanted automatically close options.

Comment: I would like for all the options to be found this way, but I am not finding the way to disable the automatic addition of " . " when editing PHP in the Web perspective. I have turned off all auto options under the "typing" search results and restarted eclipse only to be thwarted again!

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer. There are multiple configs for each type of language you are using, so the config is definitely context sensitive (e.g. Java, Javascript, HTML)  and apparently must be changed for each.

Comment: Wow, the XML editor "typing" category in the preferences is only shown, when searching for "typing". You can't navigate to this option directly...

Thanks very much.

Comment: For HTML files, you need to disable Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Typing -> "Automatically close for Attribute Values". Unlike it suggests, quotes are not only inserted for attribute values, but also when editing an HTML element's text content.

Answer (score 2):

Jump out of the quotes by simply hitting Enter when you are done typing the string contents (at least, in the java editor).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, helpful when I am escaping quotes in a code like `'\''` and do not want a closing quote I just now press enter and delete.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off auto quotes in Titanium Studio, under preferences -> Titanium Studio -> Editors -> uncheck "Auto-close matching character pairs"

Answer (score 2):

You could also hit quote when you want to exit the auto-complete quote. This will put you outside the quote as if you closed it yourself. So this feature doesn't really break the flow of you programing.

Comment: As seen in the update of the original poster this answer actually is the behavior he found to solve his problem. I don't know why people downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The location for similar auto quoting capabilities in PyDev for eclipse:
Windows -> PyDev -> Editor -> Typing -> "Automatic literal closing."

In order to enable pressing enter to exit the quotes check "Enable link on automatic parentheses or literals closing."

Answer (score 0):

As [Allethrin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444866/4430810) and [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897773/4430810) rightfully mentioned, for most of the cases you'd need "**Typing**" setting in corresponding sections of the Preferences:
[image]

Although, it might not be enough for some people.

For those who need it for a Generic Text Editor (i.e. if you struggle with automatically closing quotes in other files, like YAML, etc.), you can turn "auto-closing" off per Language Configuration under **Preferences** -> **TextMate** -> **Language Configuration** -> **Selected Content Type** -> **Auto Closing Pairs**. Just uncheck "*Enable auto closing*":
[image: Unchecked "enable auto closing" for YAML language confige]