# double quote (") is replaced by @ in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-kepler

Recently i am facing an issue in Eclipse Kepler IDE.
Whenever i press double quotes key("), @ symbol is displayed in the editor. It's annoying me.
Any idea why this happens?

Update: If i use *Shift+2*, i can see double quotes. Also, System default language is set to US. This issue is occurring only in Eclipse IDE and not any where else.
Is there anything i can do with Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Sounds like a problem not related to eclipse. Your keyboard region settings are wrong.

Comment: @Sundar does [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=78081) helps you

Comment: @Sundar Check your keyboard language settings (control panel -> keyboard and language) sounds like you are using the wrong keyboard map for your country

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you accidentally pressed Alt+Shift instead of Ctrl+Shift, which changes the keyboard layout. Pressing Alt+Shift again would fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not an eclipse issue and your keyboard input language is set to another language than default one. For example, my keyboard is Spanish and when input language is also Spanish, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is " and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is @, but when I change input to English, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is @. Check Keyboard and Languages from Control Panel!

Comment: I can see US language is set as default. Also, this problem is occurring only in eclipse. Is there anything i can do with Eclipse IDE?

Comment: HI.  I found that I can get rid of the issue in Eclipse.  In Window / Prefernces/ Editor /Typing - turn off automatic parentheses. On the other hand it is completely unclear why this problem gets started or how.  I have tried pressing "Shift-Alt" in Windows and nothing really happened.  The first time I did this a little window opened up that said "Languages." But it disappeared and then there was nothing.  However I did find This other Stack Overflow. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444845/annoying-eclipse-automatically-closing-quotes