# How to disable autocomplete of quotes and parenthesis in OMNeT++ IDE

Tags: omnet++

How do I prevent the OMNeT++ IDE from automatically closing strings (""), parenthesis, brackets, etc.? I have checked the various options in the File and Project Properties menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 1.7 of the [User Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf) states that the OMNeT++ IDE is built on top of Eclipse. According to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444866) about the Eclipse IDE, navigate to 'Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Typing' for "Automatically close" options. (alternatively, in Window -> Preferences, search for "Automatically close")

*Verified in version 5.6.2*